# Transform xml to html Golang

Tags: html, xml, go, xslt

I have xml and xslt document. How to convert my  documents to HTML document  ?

It's easy to use xslt - xml to Html in PHP. We can easily do  with  this keyword >> transformToXML.

```
<?php  
$proc=new XsltProcessor;  
$proc->importStylesheet(DOMDocument::load("data.xsl"));  
echo $proc->transformToXML(DOMDocument::load("script.xml"));  
?>
```

**But how should I do this with Golang?**

Is there an easy way or any keyword?

I could not see such a convert in the go package in the link below?
[enter link description here](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/html)

I would appreciate it if you could let me know how to proceed. Thank you.

Comment: There seems to be a package https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jbowtie/ratago/xslt#example-ParseStylesheet